# NO_DATA_FOUND exception

Tags: oracle

How do I know which `SELECT` generated the `NO_DATA_FOUND` ?

Example:

```
CREATE [..]
DECLARE
--
BEGIN
  SELECT [...];   -- will this
  SELECT [...];   -- or this to generate NO_DATA_FOUND ?
EXEPCTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  [...]
END;
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could do this:

```
DECLARE
--
BEGIN
  BEGIN
    SELECT [...];   -- will this
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      [...]
  END;
  BEGIN
    SELECT [...];   -- or this to generate NO_DATA_FOUND ?
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      [...]
  END;
END;
```

Or:

```
DECLARE
  l_where_am_i number;
BEGIN
  l_where_am_i := 1;
  SELECT [...];   -- will this
  l_where_am_i := 2;
  SELECT [...];   -- or this to generate NO_DATA_FOUND ?
EXEPCTION
  WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
    CASE l_where_am_i
       WHEN 1 THEN [...]
       WHEN 2 THEN [...]
    END CASE;
END;
```

Comment: Just a habit - l for "local" variable.  Feel free to ignore that!

Comment: @Tony: actually that `l_` owns. I will start using it too. it will be pretty useful when I need to put variables in SQL. Before I used `*_V` but `l_*` it's much better

Answer (score 2):

Another option is to use `dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace` as shown below (though it would be better to send that data to an error-logging routine).  This function will give you the actual line number the error occurred on.

```
CREATE [..]
DECLARE
--
BEGIN
  SELECT [...];   -- will this
  SELECT [...];   -- or this to generate NO_DATA_FOUND ?
EXEPCTION
WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
  [...]
  dbms_output.put_line(dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace());
END;
```

Comment: I didn't know about that utility, nice (just fyi you missed the put_line on the dmbs_output).